# Task.Run inner code not executing

Tags: c#, task

I'm writing a server-client and want to run operation using `Task.Run(() => {SomeCode});`
this Is my code

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
_control_com_peer2peer.VerifyConnection(port: 6001, IpAddressClient: ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text);
});
```

the inner code is basically

```
public void VerifyConnection(int port, string IpAddressClient)
{
Control_PeerSessionListCheckCreate(RemoteIP: IpAddressClient);
Domain_Peer2PeerCom.peerSessionList.Find(x => x.remoteIP == IpAddressClient).CommandLocker("Hello");
Domain_Peer2PeerCom.PeerSessionChangeIsConnected(IpAddressClient, true);             
}
```

I've break points inside `VerifyConnection` and none of them fire .

**EDIT**

entire code for the button firing the Task

```
private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s_RemoteIP;



    if (ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text != "")
    {
        if (Network.startPing(ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text))
        {
            Control_Peer2peerCom.Control_PeerSessionListCheckCreate(ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text);
            //bool IspeerReal = Control_Peer2peerCom.peerSessionListGet(ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text, out peerSessionCurrentParam);
            if (/*IspeerReal&&*/!(Control_Peer2peerCom.Control_PeerSessionCheckIsConnected(ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text)))//peerSessionCurrentParam.IsConnetcted))//(!Peer2peerCom.isPeerConnetionVerifaied)
            {
                SelectiveEnable();
                tbStatus.Text = "Wait...";
                tbStatus.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                s_RemoteIP = ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text;
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                 _control_com_peer2peer.VerifyConnection(port: 6001, IpAddressClient: 
                 ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text);
                });
             //more code here , Not related
             }
```

of course if I run the method out side of the `Task.Run` it runs fine

what can be the cause of it

Comment: @KarolMarianSłuszniak Why ?

Comment: @KarolMarianSłuszniak: Such an advise is useless without any explanation or example how to do it then.

Comment: @LordTitiKaka: Try to add a `try ... catch` inside the `Task.Run` and check if there is an error.

Comment: @PatrickHofman did that and yet nothing happens , Should I add more code ?

Comment: Did you write the error message to `Console` or `MessageBox`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'll do it !

Comment: How do you run the code? Are you sure that your process is kept alive long enough for the task to be able to run? If you're running this in a console application, the console app might quit before the task is scheduled to run.

Comment: @AndersAbel this is a form application and I run it on a press of a button , I have used this code many time before but now I've add the use of a static List 'PeerSessionList' , this is it :(

Comment: @PatrickHofman yet nothing happens ....

Comment: Is the Button_Click async as well? Could you post the whole code into the Task.Run Call?
Another Idea:
            TaskFactory t = new TaskFactory();
            t.StartNew(Call, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

Comment: How can I catch Exception from task ? ( I think the problem is that I'm sending the "ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text" to the task )

Answer (score 1):

the problem was in the task.run of course , once I changed to simple thread exception thrown for cross thread ! my mistake was sending `ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text` to task

the task didnt trow any exception so I want able to catch the problem

the way I've cerrected it was just adding

```
String Ipddress = ComboBoxRemoteIP.Text
```

and sending the string instead

Comment: the problem is not with `task.run`, the problem was you used `Taks` for a procedural action and didn't check for errors...

Comment: @AK_ can you explain how I correctly collect errors from Task ?? I've scatters those bloody monsters all over my code ... :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614(v=vs.110).aspx
There are also some good blog posts about this around the internet... In general Tasks are OK for functions that return something, but you should be very careful and think through every possible scenario when your'e using tasks for procedural stuff

Comment: or just use a better programming language like F# : http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/ the link also has a lot C# async pitfalls...

Comment: also read this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html